# CMake : branch on clang version

Tags: c++, cmake

How does one achieve the equivalent of the cmake branch below for clang++?

```
if (GXX_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 4.5 OR GXX_VERSION VERSION_EQUAL 4.5)
    ...
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some reason piokuc's solution doesn't work for me, so I did the following:

```
EXECUTE_PROCESS( COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} --version OUTPUT_VARIABLE clang_full_version_string )
string (REGEX REPLACE ".*clang version ([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+).*" "\\1" CLANG_VERSION_STRING ${clang_full_version_string})
if (CLANG_VERSION_STRING VERSION_GREATER 3.1)
     ....
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.2)
    ...
    ...
endif ()
```

Similarly, we have `VERSION_LESS` and `VERSION_EQUAL`.

Answer (score 4):

CMake defines following for clang:

- CLANG_VERSION_MAJOR,
- CLANG_VERSION_MINOR,
- CLANG_VERSION_PATCHLEVEL,
- and the combination of the above: CLANG_VERSION_STRING

Comment: does one need to do something to get these variables?
Using CMake 2.8.10.1 I can't use them out of the box

Comment: Have you called clang with CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/path/to/clang++ ?

Comment: You can also add  `find_package(Clang REQUIRED )` to your CMakeFiles.txt like here: https://github.com/Fadis/libdcompile/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I called clang with /usr/bin/ccache-clang++, my own wrapper. Doing find_package(Clang REQUIRED ) triggers a package not found error.

Comment: If you have installed clang in an non-standard place make sure cmake can find it; pass to cmake the directory to clang installation in -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/clang/installation/or/a/parent/directory

Comment: I just tried with the regular clang installed in a standard place, and it doesn't work any better. I'm still puzzled

Comment: @GurgHackpof: Probably your CMake version is too old. Have you tried to download a binary package from cmake.org?

Comment: @usr1234567 my post was 2 1/2 years old. CMake must be out of date indeed.

Comment: this answer does not seem correct at all, grepping for the CMake source code does not yield any reference to CLANG_VERSION_MAJOR being defined as a CMake variable (with cmake 3.21.3). Are you sure you aren't thinking of what the clang CMake package itself defines (which is only relevant if you are *linking* against the Clang libraries, not using clang as a compiler)

Answer (score 1):

Under cmake v3.1.3 I had to check CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION as there was no CLANG_VERSION_STRING so looks like a version is now defined for each compiler type giving more control.